# comparação de sessão com um campo do banco de dados em php

Tags: php

Preciso de uma ajuda. Tenho uma tabela no banco chamada textos que por sua vez tem uma coluna aluno que recebe os emails de quem está salvando textos lá. Nesta página abaixo tem q ser gerado uma tabela para cada texto do aluno daquele determinado email, ou seja, tenho que comparar o email salvo na sessão com os emails da coluna aluno da tabela textos e gerar tabelas somente para os textos do aluno daquele email específico. Porém não sei se fiz certo naquele if dentro do while. Podem me ajudar?

```
<?php require_once ("cabecalho2.php");
    require_once ("../model/banco-usuario.php");
    session_start();
    $consulta = "SELECT titulo, data, aluno FROM textos";
    $result = $conexao->query($consulta);
    ?>

    <main>
        <div class="row">
            <?php while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){
                $titulo = $dados["titulo"];
                $data = $dados["data"];
                $aluno = $dados['aluno'];
                if($_SESSION('login') = $aluno;){

                    $tabela ='<div class="col l10 s11 offset-s1" style="border: #006064 solid 3px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 6px; margin-bottom: 10px;">';
                    $tabela .= '<div class="card-panel cyan darken-4 z-depth-0" style="margin-top: 0px; border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 3px 9px 3px 9px;">';
                    $tabela .= '<h5 class="white-text light center-align" style="margin: 6px; font-size: 18px;">Tema:';
                    $tabela .= '</h5>';
                    $tabela .= '</div>';
                    $tabela .= '<div class="card-panel N/A transparent z-depth-0 col l12 s12" style="padding: 10px; margin: 0px;">';
                $tabela .= '<table class="highlight centered">';//abre table
                $tabela .='<thead>';//abre cabeçalho
                $tabela .= '<tr>';//abre uma linha
                $tabela .= '<th>Título da Redação</th>'; // colunas do cabeçalho
                $tabela .= '<th>Status da Correção</th>';
                $tabela .= '<th>Data de Envio</th>';
                $tabela .= '<th>Prazo de Entrega</th>';
                $tabela .= '<th>Ação</th>';
                $tabela .= '</tr>';//fecha linha
                $tabela .='</thead>'; //fecha cabeçalho
                $tabela .='<tbody>';//abre corpo da tabela
                /*Se você tiver um loop para exibir os dados ele deve ficar aqui*/
                $tabela .= '<tr>'; // abre uma linha
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$titulo.'</td>'; //coluna numero
                $tabela .= '<td>Corrigida</td>'; // coluna validade
                $tabela .= '<td>'.$data.'</td>'; //coluna anexo
                $tabela .= '<td>15 dias</td>';//coluna valor numero
                $tabela .= '<td><i class="small material-icons">done</i></td>'; // coluna data
                $tabela .= '</tr>'; // fecha linha
                /*loop deve terminar aqui*/
                $tabela .='</tbody>'; //fecha corpo
                $tabela .= '</table>';//fecha tabela
                $tabela .= '</div>';
                $tabela .= '</div>';

                echo $tabela;
            }
        }?>

    </div>
    </main>

    <?php include 'rodape.php';
    die();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, você quer pegar apenas os emails do aluno em questão? (O que está logado?)

Se for, tente fazer algo como:

```
$consulta = "SELECT titulo, data, aluno FROM textos WHERE aluno = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";
```

Remova está linha também, afinal, passamos a comparação na busca do banco

if($_SESSION('login') = $aluno;){

Não esqueça de remover o } restante.

OBS: imagino que o que está armazenado na sessão login é o que irá comparar no banco, senão for, troque para o correto

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado me ajudou muito.